# Python replace str in list with new value

Tags: python, list, replace

I’m writing a program that makes music albums into files that you can search for, and for that i need a str in the file that have a specific value that is made after the list is complete. Can you go back in that list and change a blank str with a new value?

I have searched online and found something called words.replace, but it doesn’t work, i get a Attribute error.

```
def create_album():
    global idnumber, current_information
    file_information = []
    if current_information[0] != 'N/A':
        save()
    file_information.append(idnumber)
    idnumber += 1
    print('Type c at any point to abort creation')
    for i in creation_list:
        value = input('\t' + i)
        if value.upper == 'C':
            menu()
        else:
            -1file_information.append('')
            file_information.append(value)
    file_information.append('Album created - ' + file_information[2] +'\nSongs:')
    -2file_information = [w.replace(file_information[1], str(file_information[0]) + '-' + file_information[2]) for w in file_information]
    current_information = file_information

    save_name = open(save_path + str(file_information[0]) + '-' + str(file_information[2]) + '.txt', 'w')
    for i in file_information:
        save_name.write(str(i) + '\n')

    current_files_ = open(information_file + 'files.txt', 'w')
    filenames.append(file_information[0])
    for i in filenames:
        current_files_.write(str(i) + '\n')

    id_file = open(information_file + 'albumid.txt', 'w')
    id_file.write(str(idnumber))
```

-1 is where i have put aside a blank row

-2 is the where i try to replace row 1 in the list with the value of row 0 and row 2.

The error message I receive is ‘int’ object has no attribute ‘replace’

Comment: What if you do str(w).replace?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
`print` the offending values just before the point of failure.  Your posted code doesn't run as given.

Comment: @prune So i should just print the entire script?

Comment: No, that's not what the link tells you.

Comment: @AlexisCôté it runs the code, but the output is completely wrong

Comment: @Prune i get that, but in my case i have supporting files that is needed to create the same error.

Comment: The error you've partially described depends on a handful of local references.  Again, refer to the link concerning how to present a MCVE.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
-2file_information = [w.replace(str(file_information[1]), str(file_information[0]) + '-' + file_information[2]) for w in file_information]
```